# Failing to launch Intent when Action is set

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I'm building multiple productFlavors of an app. When I launch an intent and only set the package then the app launches fine. When I set the action it no longer works.

The end goal is to be able to go back and forth between the two apps. I'm relatively new to Android so I'd appreciate any help! I believe the package name is correct so I'm not sure why the action is not working. Not sure which part is what I should focus on.

Im changing the appId which presumably changes the packageName so that android knows they are separate apps.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("fitpay.issuerDemo.authenticate_user"); //without this line it goes to the correct activity although i
intent.setPackage("fitpay.issuerDemo");
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(intent, A2A_VERIFICATION_REQUEST);
}
```

flavor AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application>
    <activity
        android:name="fitpay.pagare.activities.SimulatedAppToAppActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="fitpay.issuerDemo.generate_auth_code" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="fitpay.issuerDemo.authenticate_user" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="fitpay.issuerDemo.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/image_path" />
    </provider>

</application>
```

App .gradle:

```
 productFlavors {
    wvUI {
        dimension "default"
    }
    nativeUI {
        dimension "default"
    }
    issuerDemo {
        applicationId "fitpay.issuerDemo"
        dimension "default"
    }
}

sourceSets {
    wvUI {
        java {
            srcDirs('src/wvUI/java', 'src/qa/java')
        }
    }
    nativeUI {
        java {
            srcDirs('src/nativeUI/java', 'src/qa/java')
        }
    }
    issuerDemo {
        java {
            srcDirs('src/issuerDemo/java', 'src/qa/java')
        }
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
package fitpay.pagare.activities;

public class SimulatedAppToAppActivity extends BaseActivity {
}
```

Comment: I tried adding `intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);` with the same issue. I get a compile error when trying to call setComponent with a string.

Comment: setComponent expects a component not a string. specifically `error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to ComponentName` I also don't want to couple my implementation to a specific activity name but let the receiving app handle that.

Comment: get class name and package in first app using `SimulatedAppToAppActivity.class` and `getPackage()` then use them in second app in `intent.setComponent(your_package, class_name)`

Comment: no luck setting the component that way. It does nothing when that is added.